# How can I de-brand my phone? (install vanilla Android?)

Tags: vanilla-android

I bought a cheap handset (XTE San Francisco, 2.1) from the Orange provider.

I'm not a regular Orange customer so I had it unlocked so I could use my existing SIM.

Orange seem to pre-load their devices with a bunch of useless stuff. Which is now even more useless since I can't access any of them.

Is there anyway I can remove these? I would prefer not to "root" my device if possible.

What about installing the vanilla version of Android, such as the flavour which the SDK emulator has?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/what-is-involved-in-installing-android-onto-a-device

Comment: Why avoid root? flashing a new ROM will void your warranty just as much as rooting. If it is a security fear just unroot after removing the bloatware.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options I know of to 'de-Orange' the San Francisco. You can use something like [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) (requires root) to remove the Orange apps, or install a custom ROM.

On my San Francisco I rooted the phone (see first part of this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E28U0t5RZz8), full details and file downloads [here](http://android.modaco.com/content/zte-blade-blade-modaco-com/318413/04-oct-r3-superboot-root-mcri/), or alternatively you could use [Super One Click](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682)) and then used [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to uninstall the Orange apps (list in [this thread](http://android.modaco.com/content/zte-blade-blade-modaco-com/321479/remove-orange-apps-on-san-francisco/)). If in doubt, TB lets you 'freeze' apps so you can make sure everything still works before uninstalling fully.

Alternatively, you can install a custom ROM (see [full video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E28U0t5RZz8)) which I haven't done yet (waiting to see if FroYo ROM becomes available).

Answer (score 2):

There's a full on guide to installing android 2.2 here [orangesanfrancisco.co.uk](http://orangesanfrancisco.co.uk)