# Google Android for Galaxy Note II?

Tags: rom, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Hey guys is it possible to get the stock android OS like on the Google Nexus and install it on the Galaxy Note II? I'm just tired of the bloatware and I also prefer the OS on my friends Galaxy Nexus much more.. I don't want to install a custom ROM but the same one that is used on the new Google Nexus 4

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [How can I de-brand my phone? (install vanilla Android?)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3133), [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152), [Can you install vanilla Android on any phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38074)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any official ROM from Samsung for Galaxy Note that does not contain any of their framework application.

Your only option is to install custom ROM. CyanogenMod will be one of the best choices since it's build based on AOSP.