# What's involved in manually updating my Nexus One?

Tags: nexus-one, updates

If I wanted to manually update my Nexus One, say to Gingerbread, what's involved in the process?

I'm familiar with this question, [Manually Updating your OS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/manually-updating-your-os), but unsure if the answer applies to the Nexus One. Do I need to root my phone in order to update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is no official update for the N1 to Gingerbread yet.

However, you could root your phone and install CyanogenMod 7 (nightly, it hasn't hit release candidate yet) to get Gingerbread on your phone.  From what I've heard, the nightlies have been pretty stable for the N1.

[More details on the CM wiki here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Nexus_One).

Basic steps include:

1. Root your phone
2. Install ROM Manager
3. Flash ClockWork Recovery
4. MAKE A NANDROID BACKUP OF YOUR PHONE
5. Flash CM7

Note: rooting your phone will void your warranty.  For more info about rooting, see [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what).

Comment: Thanks for the information, what if there was an official update, what would be involved in updating the phone?

Comment: @James If/when there is an official update, then as long as you haven't manually installed a custom ROM like this, then your phone will automatically download the update shortly after it's released, and then show a message asking if you want to update now.

Comment: @James as GAThrawn said, you'll receive an OTA update from Google/carrier if you are running stock Android

Answer (score 1):

It's going to vary a bit by device and OS version.

I did find [this](http://www.intomobile.com/2011/02/24/how-to-manually-update-your-nexus-one-to-android-2-3-3/) however, which is specifically for updating the Nexus One to Android 2.3.3 (which is out officially).

> Sick of waiting for your Nexus One to get the OTA update to Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread? It’s your lucky day, as you can now manually install the update to your phone without anymore waiting!
>
> 1. Download the Nexus One update from this link [here](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/passion/81304b2de707.signed-passion-GRI40-from-FRG83G.81304b2d.zip).
> 2. Rename the file to update.zip (If your OS hides file extensions by default, rename the file to **update** to avoid it being renamed to update.zip.zip)
> 3. Connect your Nexus One to your computer and transfer the file to the root of the microSD card (inside no folders)
> 4. Power down the Nexus One. Now reboot it by holding the **Power and Volume Down** at the same time.
> 5. You should now see a screen with Androids on skateboards. Using the **Volume keys**, navigate to **Recovery** and press **Power**.
> 6. The recovery screen will only show a triangle with an exclamation point in it. To get to the recovery menu press **Power and Volume Up** at the same time. (It can be a bit tricky sometimes, so keep trying if it doesn’t work the first time)
> 7. Using the **trackball**, scroll down and select “**Apply sdcard:update.zip.**” to start the update.
> 8. Once the update has completed, reboot your Nexus One.
>
> You’ve successfully updated to Android 2.3.3. Have fun!

Comment: Says e-signature verification failed :\

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide any further guidance. (I don't have a Nexus.) You should check with the source.