# How can I force my Nexus One to upgrade to the official Gingerbread without waiting for the formal OTA update?

Tags: nexus-one, 2.3-gingerbread

The OTA update for Gingerbread is being pushed out. But I'm in India and there's a good chance I'll be among the last people to get it. Is there a way to get that official update right now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only one way. Keep checking xda developers forum for update.zip link. Once you get it download and update manually. This is the only way to get gingerbread update on your phone. Else it will take few weeks (as per google definition few weeks is 3+ months).

Comment: I agree, XDA will have it ASAP.

Comment: This is what I would do if syntheticbrain's suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: And here it is http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11566707

Comment: Thanks, that was really simple! Next question is, how does one get information on when Google releases a signed OTA file for manual update? Do you need to be a registered Android developer for that?

Comment: It's generally just the good people at xda who 'release' the file for manual update. I don't think google, or device manufactures, ever really officially release them.

Answer (score 2):

A comment on the checkin procedure: you need to enter `*#*#2432546#*#*` without pressing dial. (The numbes are equivalent to checkin, I just think this is clearer.)

More specifically, the general consensus seems to be that the phone polls for available updates periodically (to the OS and apps). This procedure forces it to poll, but if the OS update has not been made available to you it won't do anything.

Comment: If you put the code in between backticks `` Markdown won't read the asterisks as the code for Italics.

Comment: There was a suggestion on xda which said that one should put the phone on airplane mode, switch on wifi and then repeat the process. This way you have a better chance of getting the OTA coming your way. But seems that the checkin process only works if your model/ carrier is anyways scheduled for an OTA update.

Answer (score 1):

Try Settings -> About phone -> System updates

If that isn't available, or doesn't work, try typing `*#*#checkin#*#*` into the dialer. As a disclaimer, I haven't myself tried the second method, but have read it is meant to work.

Comment: I tried this on my Nexus S and got an invalid code error - still might be valid for Nexus One though. You said you "read" about this code working. Can you site the source please? I'd like to read it also.

Comment: http://jeftek.com/622/how-to-force-checking-for-updates-on-android-devices/ It does actually mention it should be done with the stock dialer, which I hadn't noticed. Though the Nexus S is using stock, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can install it manually, I followed [these instructions](http://www.everythingandroid.org/update-your-nexus-one-to-android-2-3-gingerbread/2011/02/24/).

1. [Download the update](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/passion/81304b2de707.signed-passion-GRI40-from-FRG83G.81304b2d.zip) and rename the file update.zip
2. Connect your Nexus One to your PC/Mac and copy that file to your microSD card.
3. Power down your Nexus One. Then press ‘power’ and hold the trackball.
   1 . You’ll see a screen appear with three Android robots and you’ll see some code. Using the volume buttons, select ‘Bootloader’ and then press ‘Power’ to select.
4. On the next screen, select ‘Recovery’.
5. The Nexus One will reboot. You’ll see a triangle with and Android robot and an exclamation point.
6. Press the volume up button and the power button at the same time.
7. Using the trackball, select “Apply sdcard: update.zip”.

I then rebooted and now I have 2.3.

- [What's involved in manually updating my Nexus One?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/whats-involved-in-manually-updating-my-nexus-one/6428#6428)