# How to flash a RUU on a rooted HTC One X (Evita) using TWRP

Tags: rom-flashing

Is it possible to flash a ruu on a rooted HTC One X (Evita).

Actually, I have a AT&T HTC One X (evita) and I want to flash with an international rom of HTC One XL. It will be good if any one know a link of rooted stock rom of HTC One XL international version. 
I am no more using AT&T and dont want any AT&T apps.

Comment: Have you checked the [most frequent rom-flashing questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rom-flashing?sort=frequent)? For your case, e.g. [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) / [What is involved in installing Android onto a device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2575/16575). Also, check [questions tagged 'rom-flashing' AND 'htc-one-x'](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rom-flashing+htc-one-x).

Comment: If I unroot HOX, will I be able to flash a international HTC One XL RUU(Not AT&T). I have a SuperCID, RUU will work for SuperCID

Answer (score 0):

RUUs are flashed using the bootloader, not recovery. Reboot into the bootloader and install using fastboot.