# How to install stock android on Huawei P9?

Tags: stock-android, huawei

As you may know, Huawei ships its devices with their very own Emotion UI. I recently received such a device and was shocked someone willingly destroyed such a great phone with such a bad UI. It especially hurt, since I was coming from a Nexus device.

Due how extensive the problems are, there is no remedy other than installing stock android. But, is it a working remedy? Am I able to find stock android installation, which supports fingerprints and double back camera?

Comment: [This question about a different phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131850/is-it-possible-to-install-stock-android) explains why it's not as simple as just "installing stock android".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't expect **anything** for phones running Kirin SoCs, at least for the foreseeable years.

AFAIK, only the Honor 6 generation (Kirin 920) received CM11 treatment, but it still is buggy and development never proceeded beyond Lollipop despite the phone having official Marshmallow. Huawei is (intentionally) making unlock harder and development resources hard to obtain so as to hamper third-party development.

Sell and grab another Nexus/OnePlus, and get some spare money in the process, simple as that.

**EDIT**: As of now, recent Huawei flagships such as [P8](https://forum.xda-developers.com/huawei-p8/development/rom-huawei-p8-unofficial-cyanogenmod-13-t3451457), [P9](https://forum.xda-developers.com/p9/development/rom-t3483134) and [Mate 8](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mate-8/development/6-0-1-cyanogenmod-13-port-t3512985) have received CyanogenMod (LineageOS) 13 (Android 6.0) treatment. Those builds, however, are far from daily-driver status, lacking basic features such as camera and hardware acceleration. There's also no sign of Nougat on the horizon, since official Nougat for those phones are in beta at best. Unless the open-source situation of Kirin changes, this will continue to be the norm.

Answer (score 0):

> willingly destroyed such a great phone with such a bad UI. It
>   especially hurt, since I was coming from a Nexus device.
>
> Due to the above, there is no remedy other than installing stock
>   android. But, is it a working remedy? Am I able to find stock android
>   installation, which supports fingerprints and double back camera?

Your best hope is that some one creates a AOSP-ROM for your device. But looking in http://forum.xda-developers.com/p9 forums there is none. Since you say you came from nexus device I can only hope next time you make some  searches in XDA or get.cm where you can find most popular devices. For the moment P9 has some ROMs in xda but not as clean as AOSP.

Comment: Like I said, 'I recently _received_ such a device' - Nexus would have been, indeed, my choice otherwise. Selling the Huawei and getting a Nexus is probably the optimal solution, like others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I share your view on the notification (a real pain in the ass). I found a partial fix (but still got some issue, like with Airbnb) : http://www.forbes.com/sites/bensin/2016/07/04/push-notifications-not-coming-through-to-your-huawei-phone-heres-how-to-fix-it/#3390958978aa

Regarding the launcher, you can install one, then : Settings > Apps > Advanced > Default Apps > then choose your app (such as the launcher)